# Reverse the rows of a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Yesterday I asked a very similar question and I kind of messed up with asking it.

I need to pass an array to a method and inside of that method I need to swap the rows around so if it's

`1 2 3`

`3 2 1`

`2 1 3`

it needs to be

`3 2 1`

`1 2 3`

`3 1 2`

With the code I have right now it swaps the last column to the first column spot correctly then it puts the column that's supposed to be last.

`3 1 2`

`1 3 2`

`3 2 1`

Also, it needs to stay a void because I need to be modifying the original array so I can't set it as a temp array but I can use a temp integer to store.

Here is the code I have right now that's sort of working

```
public static void reverseRows(int[][] inTwoDArray)
{
   for (int row = 0; row < inTwoDArray.length; row++)
   {
       for (int col = 0; col < inTwoDArray[row].length; col++)
       {
           int tempHolder = inTwoDArray[row][col];
           inTwoDArray[row][col] = inTwoDArray[row][inTwoDArray[0].length - 1];
           inTwoDArray[row][inTwoDArray[0].length - 1] = tempHolder;
       }
    }
 }
```

any help would be great, I'm running out of hair to pull out! Thanks!

Comment: Start by extracting the algorithm to reverse a 1-D array into a method. That will already make the code easier to understand, and solve one of the bugs. Then execute your reverse algorithm on paper, noting the value of each variable at each instruction. You'll understand where it's wrong.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for the response! I'm currently trying to do that. So do you mean I would make `int tempHolder = inTwoDArray[row]`?

Comment: The algorithm should be: for each row in the 2D array, reverse the row. In java: `for (int[] row : inTwoDArray) { reverse(row); }`. Isn't that easier to read and understand? Now you just need to concentrate on the implementation of the reverse() method, which deals with a 1-D, int[] array.

Comment: @JBNizet thank you, thank you, thank you so much! You made me understand why it worked and kuba illustrated it in code. Got it working, can't thank you guys enough and everyone else!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, how to reverse a single 1-D array:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length / 2; i++) {
    int temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[array.length - i - 1];
    array[array.length - i - 1] = temp;
}
```

Note that you must stop in half of your array or you would swap it twice (it would be the same one you started with).

Then put it in another for loop:

```
for(int j = 0; j < array.length; j++){
    for(int i = 0; i < array[j].length / 2; i++) {
        int temp = array[j][i];
        array[j][i] = array[j][array[j].length - i - 1];
        array[j][array[j].length - i - 1] = temp;
    }
}
```

Another approach would be to use some library method such as from [`ArrayUtils#reverse()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html):

```
ArrayUtils.reverse(array);
```

And then again put into a cycle:

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
   ArrayUtils.reverse(array[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! It's been about 5 hours straight so my brain was stuck and just about mush. You guys saved me!

Comment: @iHeff No problem :) Sometimes what helps is to draw it on a piece of paper or debugging would have shown the problem as well.

Comment: I work on websites a lot and usually paper is my best friend but for some reason its hard to illustrate on paper when working on java. Once I get a better understanding though I'm sure it'll come easier, thanks for the tip! And I forgot how to debug with blueJ then completely forgot how important it is. Should have done that, oops. Thanks!! @Kuba Spatny

Comment: I guess it is proper :-                                                                             for(int j = 0; j < array.length; j++){
    for(int i = 0; i < array[j].length / 2; i++) {
        int temp = array[j][i];
        array[j][i] = array[j][array.length - i - 1];
        array[j][array.length - i - 1] = temp;
    }
} As above mentioned code is giving error for me? Am i correct?

Comment: array[j][i] = array[j][array[j].length - i - 1];
array[j][array[j].length - i - 1] = temp;                                                                    instead of                                                                                                                    array[j][i] = array[j][array.length - i - 1];
array[j][array.length - i - 1] = temp;

Comment: the above code works only for sqaur matrix. I have added my answer below.

Comment: @ChandanaSen I have reviewed your edit and fixed the code. It will hopefully work now.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I didn't confuse what array stores the rows and which one the columns.... but this should work (long time since I've done Java last, so be nice to me when spotting any errors please ^^):

```
public static void reverseRows(int[][] array)
{
    for (int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++) {       // for each row...
        int[] reversed = new int[array[i].length];   // ... create a temporary array that will hold the reversed inner one ...
        for(int j = 0 ; j < array[i].length ; j++) { // ... and for each column ...
            reversed[reversed.length - 1 - j] = array[i][j]; // ... insert the current element at the mirrored position of our temporary array
        }
        array[i] = reversed; // finally use the reversed array as new row.
    }
}
```

Comment: looks great except I'm not able make a temporary array for this (it's a program for a class) I wish I could because I would be done hours ago hahaha. Thanks though!! (and I didn't see any errors but my java isn't very advanced!)

Answer (score 1):

I guess this the easiest approach, tried and tested
For instance, you have

```
1 2
3 4
```

and you want

```
2 1 
4 3
```

You can reverse the loop, without any extra space or inbuilt function.
Solution:

```
for(int i =0;i<arr.length;i++) //arr.length=no of rows
{
  for(int j = arr[i].length-1;j>=0;j--)//arr[i].length=no of col in a ith row
    {
        System.out.print(arr[i][j]+" ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java Code :-

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Rev_Two_D {

    static int col;
    static int row;
    static int[][] trans_arr = new int[col][row];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int m = sc.nextInt();
        row = m;
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        col = n;
        int[][] arr = new int[row][col];

        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                arr[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
                System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < arr[j].length / 2; i++) {
                int temp = arr[j][i];
                arr[j][i] = arr[j][arr[j].length - i - 1];
                arr[j][arr[j].length - i - 1] = temp;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reverse of two D array - Print your two D array in reverse order

```
public void reverse(){
    int row = 3;
    int col = 3;
    int[][] arr = new int[row][col];
    int k=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++,k++) {
            arr[i][j] = k;
            System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = arr.length -1; i >=0 ; i--) {
        for (int j = arr.length -1; j >=0 ; j--) {
            System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int [][] a={{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12},{13,14,15,16}};

    for(int i=0 ; i<a.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0 ; j<a.length;j++)
        {
            System.out.print(a[i][j]+",");
        }
        System.out.println();

    }
    System.out.println("***************************");
    for(int i=0 ; i<a.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=a.length-1 ; j>=0;j--)
        {
            System.out.print(a[i][j]+",");
        }
        System.out.println();

    }

}
```

Comment: Note: the first line of your answer/code is not formatted as code; you might want to fix that. Also, maybe you want to add your comment as text to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

***Reverse 2 D Array***

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

int a[][] =  {{1,2,3},
              {4,5,6},
              {8,9,10,12,15}
              };

for(int i=0 ; i<a.length;i++)
{
    for(int j=0 ; j<a[i].length;j++)
    {
        System.out.print(a[i][j]+",");
    }
    System.out.println();

}

for(int i=0 ; i<a.length;i++)
{
    for(int j=a[i].length-1 ; j>=0;j--)
    {
        System.out.print(a[i][j]+",");
    }
    System.out.println();

}
```