# How to reverse a 2D array in the Y direction?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

```
{{1, 2},{2, 3}, {3, 4}};
```

How could I reverse the values at index 1 of each sub array to change the array to:

```
{{1, 4},{2, 3}, {3, 2}};
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? This is just a requirements dump. We won't do your homework for you.

Comment: I don't understand the transformation.  Can you explain it more clearly?

Comment: [Reverse the rows of a 2d array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21920939/reverse-the-rows-of-a-2d-array#21921221) This question any help?

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
    b[i][0] = a[i][0];
    b[i][1] = a[a.length-i-1][1];
    System.out.println(b[i][0] + " " + b[i][1]);
}
```